# How to write YUV 420 video frames from RGB data using OpenCV or other image processing library?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, yuv

I have an array of rgb data generated from glReadPixels().
Note that RGB data is pixel packed (r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2,...).

How can I quickly write a YUV video frame using OpenCV or another C++ library, so that I can stream them to FFMPEG? Converting RGB pixel to YUV pixel is not a problem, as there are many conversion formula available online. However writing the YUV frame is the main problem for me. I have been trying to write the YUV video frame since the last few days and were not successful in doing that.

This is one of my other question about writing YUV frame and the issues that I encountered: [Issue with writing YUV image frame in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858388/need-help-writing-yuv-image-frame-in-c-c)
I don't know what is wrong with my current approach in writing the YUV frame to a file.

So right now I may want to use existing library (if any), that accepts an RGB data, and convert them to YUV and write the YUV frame directly to a file or to a pipe. Of course it would be much better if I can fix my existing program to write the YUV frame, but you know, there is also a deadline in every software development project, so time is also a priority for me and my project team members.

Comment: Have you tried swscale in FFMPEG? Converting pixel format and scaling image with swscale only need like 3 lines of code.

Comment: Why do you have to stream YUV data to FFmpeg? Why not just feed the RGB data?

Comment: no library is required to write a YUV frame. You said you can convert the RGB data to Y,U and V. Just write that data in a file with the same order. You can subsample the U & V by taking the alternate values. Then you just need a good YUV player to view that file. I've done this multiple times, its very easy.

Comment: @TheJuice: So I have an OpenGL application running, and I want to capture the animation display (using glReadPixels), then I want to pipe this data to FFMPEG and use Red5 server to stream it to a web browser as RTMP live streaming. I learned from http://kylecordes.com/2007/pipe-ffmpeg and also other related websites, that FFMPEG can receive input data through pipe but the data has to be encoded in YUV video frames format. Could you guide me into the right approach in solving this? Here is my current approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858388/need-help-writing-yuv-image-frame-in-c-c

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg will happily receive RGB data in.  You can see what pixel formats FFmpeg supports by running:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts
```

Any entry with an `I` in the first column can be used as an input.

Since you haven't specified the pixel bit depth, I am going to assume it's 8-bit and use the `rgb8` pixel format.  So to get FFmpeg to read rgb8 data from `stdin` you would use the following command (I am `cat`ing data in but you would be supplying via your pipe):

```
cat data.rgb | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb8 -s WIDTHxHEIGHT -i pipe:0 output.mov
```

Since it is a raw pixel format with no framing, you need to subsitite WIDTH and HEIGHT for the appropriate values of your image dimensions so that FFmpeg knows how to frame the data.

I have specifed the output as a MOV file but you would need to configure your FFmpeg/Red5 output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV does not support the YUV format directly, as you know, so it's really up to you to find a way to do **RGB <-> YUV** conversions.

[This is a very interesting post](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/59027) as it shows **how to load and create YUV frames on the disk**, while storing the data as `IplImage`.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg will write an AVI file with YUV but as karl says there isn't direct support for it in openCV.

Alternatively (and possibly simpler) you can just write the raw UYVY values to a file and then use ffmpeg to convert it to an AVI/MP4 in any format you want. It's also possible to write directly to a pipe and call ffmpeg directly from your app avoiding the temporary yuv file

eg. to convert an HD yuv422 stream to a h264 MP4 file at 30fps

`ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuyv422 -s 1920x1080 -i input.yuv -vcodec libx264 -x264opts -r 30 output.mp4`

Comment: So I have an OpenGL application running, and I want to capture the animation display (using glReadPixels), then I want to pipe this data to FFMPEG and use Red5 to stream it to a web browser as RTMP live streaming. I learned from kylecordes.com/2007/pipe-ffmpeg and also other related websites, that FFMPEG can receive RTMP streaming data through pipe but the data has to be encoded in YUV video frames format. Could you guide me into the right approach? Here is my current approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858388/  which I referred from http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=YUV4MPEG2

Comment: @all_by_grace - if you are reading a screen in RGB wouldn't it be simpler to write those values directly? ffmpeg and openCV can both create video from RGB pixel formats. ps you aren't going to be able to handle a very high frame rate in either case unless you have a very fancy raid system